# Trailing `000000000000003` with SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following schema and data in database:

```sql
Create table Scores (Id int, Score NUMBER(3,2))
Truncate table Scores
insert into Scores (Id, Score) values ('1', '3.5')
insert into Scores (Id, Score) values ('2', '3.65')
insert into Scores (Id, Score) values ('3', '4.0')
insert into Scores (Id, Score) values ('4', '3.85')
insert into Scores (Id, Score) values ('5', '4.0')
insert into Scores (Id, Score) values ('6', '3.65')
```

I wrote following query:

```sql
SELECT Score, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Score DESC) AS Rank FROM Scores;
```

It works well on most of results. But sometimes I get values for `Scores` with trailing `0` and `3` at the end, for example: `57.43000000000000003`.

Could someone please explain why is it happening?

UPDATE:

Solving this questions:  https://leetcode.com/problems/rank-scores/

Added `ROUND(Score, 2)` and it works fine. But still not clear with trailing zeros.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Oracle 12.2.0.1. Why are you inserting numbers as string literals? btw there is no `If Not Exists` clause.

Comment: That looks like floating point fuzziness. Are you sure you're using Oracle DBMS rather than (say) MySQL?

Comment: Yes. Oracle SQL.

Comment: @William Robertson it is example provided by leetcode for mysql database. Not sure why.

Comment: So the problem is with leetcode, not Oracle. Does it still happen if you use numeric values instead of strings?

Comment: The code you've shown won't run on Oracle, and the data you've presented doesn't cause the problems you've reported.